# Is this homology sequence right?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be a Lie Group and $H$ a closed normal subgroup of $G$. Then $G/H$ is also a Lie group. Denote $\pi: G\to G/H$ as the usual projection of Lie groups $\pi(g) = gH$.

Now, consider the short exact sequence on the complex chains 
$$\{1\} \rightarrow C_n(H) \xrightarrow[]{i_\#} C_n(G) \xrightarrow[]{\pi_\#} C_n(G/H)  \rightarrow \{1\},\quad \quad (*)$$
where, if $\sigma: \Delta^n \to H$, then
$$i_{\#}(\sigma) = i\circ \sigma = \sigma,\ i\text{ is the inclusion map,}  $$
and $i_{\#}$ is extended in a linear fashion. 
In the same way, if $\omega: \Delta^n \to G$, then
$$ \pi_\# (\omega) = \pi \circ \omega, $$
and once again,  $\pi_\#$ is extended in a linear fashion, it is easy to check that $(*)$ is an exact sequence.

Moreover, it is clear that $\partial\circ i_\# = i_\# \circ\partial$, and 
\begin{align*}
\pi_\# (\partial\omega) &= \pi_\# \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left.\omega\right|_{[e_0,...\hat{e_i},...,e_n]}\right)\\  
&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left.\pi_{\#}\omega\right|_{[e_0,...\hat{e_i},...,e_n]}\right)\\  
&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left.\pi\circ\omega\right|_{[e_0,...\hat{e_i},...,e_n]}\right)\\ 
&=\partial (\pi\circ \omega)\\
&=\partial \pi_\# ( \omega)\\ 
\end{align*}
implying $\partial \circ \pi_{\#} = \pi_{\#}\circ \partial$. So we can induce a long exact sequence in homology

$$...\to H_{n+1}(G/H)\to H_{n}(H)\to H_{n}(G)\to H_{n}(G/H) \to H_{n-1}(H)\to ... $$

It is right the above long exact sequence? I am asking it here because I did not find such a sequence anywhere and differential topology is not my specialty, so I would like some confirmation.

Comment: Your "short exact sequence" (*) isn't exact.  The quotient is the relative chain group $C_n(G,H)$ not the chain group $C_n(G/H)$.

Comment: If $\pi\circ \sigma = 1_{G/H}$, then $\text{Im}(\sigma) \subset H$, isn't ?

Comment: I think that I understand now what is happening, $\sigma(x) = 1_{G/H}$, is not the neutral element of the chain $C_n(G/H)$.

Comment: it is correct that $\pi_\# i_\# =0$. This issue is exactness. In vague terms, $\pi_\#$ "kills too much". Think about the situation $G = U(1)$ and $H= \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: @BrianShin I think that the problem is because $\pi_{\#}i_{\#}\neq 0$. Note $\pi_{\#}i_{\#}\sigma = 1_{G/H}\neq 0$

Comment: Ah, indeed, I too am misinterpreting things.